How to make PyTorch Geometric DataLoader to create multiple graphs in batch instead of one giant graph?
PyTorch Geometric DataLoader, while using batches with sizes greater than 1, creates a large graph with isolated subgraphs, instead of a list of graphs with padding to equal size. Unfortunately, this way is inappropriate for my task. So is there a way to make PyTorch Geometric DataLoader create a list of graphs instead of one large graph?
